# Visual Sourcesafe can deploy files, not folders

Tags: ftp, visual-sourcesafe

We recently got new computers, and can no longer deploy project folders, only individual files. If we attempt to deploy a project folder, it displays a general error message, for example:

> Could not deploy $/.../index.html to ftp://...

Anyone know why this is the case? We still have administrative rights on the new computers, and our old computers can still complete the deploy, so I don't think it's a network issue.

Answer (score 0):

We discovered our IT department replaced McAfee with Kaspersky AV on the new computers and that was blocking the deploy request.